# C#: Debug.Assert() in Release-Build-DLL seems to be activated by Debug-Build-Project

Tags: c#, dll, assert

I have an DLL with a lot of Debug.Assert() calls.
I have built this DLL as Release, so the Assert are not be active (I checked this with a small test programm).
Now I use this DLL in a software project which is a Debug-Build and for some reason the Asserts from the DLL are active again.
Does the DEBUG definition of the project reactivate the asserts in the DLL? 
(VisualStudio 2013)

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) states:

> When the C# compiler encounters an #if directive, followed eventually by an #endif directive, it will compile the code between the directives only if the specified symbol is defined.

Considering this I would say you should not see these asserts, because when compiling in Release mode the code should have been left out.

You could try to decompile your release assembly and see if the code was generated.

Comment: There isn't actually a #if/#endif. The Debug.Assert ist defined like this:         
'[Conditional("DEBUG")]
 public static void Assert(bool condition);'

Comment: Yes, but looking at the Assert source it seems to be using the #IF. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bcldebug.cs,108